# Docusign api: create a new user with active status Not working

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create users in docusing using the API. I have implemented all related to jwt authentication. In fact, I made some test and the connection to the API using the Bearer token works. I tried to create an employee using "POST [https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/{ORGANIZATION_ID}/users"](https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/%7BORGANIZATION_ID%7D/users%22) and it worked. After this test I realize that the userStatus of the account is ActivationSent, not Active. I've done a little research and I found out that to create an active user it has to be done in a different way (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/how-to/create-active-user/). I have tried to do it as the tutorial says, but it does not work. Every time I send the POST the response is unauthorized. I'm not sure why if I use the same bearer token that works for other operations.

Any ideas?

Regards
Lórien

Comment: If you're getting an HTML response, that typically means you're hitting a URL that isn't an API endpoint. From the screenshot, it looks like you may be hitting the account server (`account-d.docusign.com`) instead of the API domain (`api-d.docusign.net`). Are you sure your URLs are accurate?

Comment: Wow!! what a stupid mistake! yes, that was the issue. I focused on the last part fo the URL and didn't even notice the first part was wrong :( Thank you very much!!! Now it works, but the message is unauthorized. Isn't the bearer token enough to create an user like this?

Comment: Your new user email must be the same as the claimed domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a user via the Admin API, your token must include the `user_write` scope. Additionally, in order to create a user in to the `Activated` status, their email address must be under a Claimed Domain with SSO configured and "Require all users to authenticate with Identity Provider" and "Auto-activate manually added memberships and suppress activation emails" set on the domain.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Now I have another question. Once the user is closed, how can I reactivate it as active? I have tried using the insert Json but adding the closed user id, but did not work, a new one was created. How can I reactivate a user as active without sending the activation mail?

Comment: Hello @lbarbero003 - Silently Reactivating a closed user is quite a bit more complicated. Could you post a separate question for that?